# Honeywell 880 weather radar malfunctioning

Tags: weather, weather-radar

Is anyone aware of issues with the Honeywell 880 weather radar not painting moisture?   We had our original 800 unit go bad on our Falcon 7X,  We have installed 3 replacements that have hardware and software upgrades.  We have inspected the flate plate, radome, wires, bonding points etc.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be addressed to Honeywell???

Comment: Painting moisture is pretty much all it does.  You mean it will paint terrain if you point it down, but not rain?

Comment: Well, it's been exceptionally dry this summer, the weather radar is probably just fine! 

Welcome to aviation.stackexchange, Mark! Whilst you might find people here who are able to suggest troubleshooting best practices, I think the best approach in this case is to contact Honeywell.